# When/If you eat KFC chicken, you are a fast food lover. - do they mean different to you?

Tags: meaning, conditionals

A lot of online materials say “if” and “when” are interchangeable when the conditional sentence is something repeated and habitual.

But I just found an exception.

(1)

> If you eat KFC chicken, you are a fast food lover.

(2)

> When you eat KFC chicken, you are a fast food lover.

(2) sounds like during the time you eat KFC chicken are you a fast food lover.

So I guess the rule that "when" and "if" are interchangeable is not universal. Am I correct?

Comment: They're certainly *not* interchangeable! The "when" version doesn't really make sense, because being a lover of fast food is a relatively *permanent* characteristic - you don't just become one temporarily while eating KFC.

Comment: But you could say "When you try KFC, you'll *become* a fast-food lover" or "When you eat KFC more than ____ times a month, face facts, you're a fast-food lover".

Answer (score 1):

As what @FumbleFingers commented, the *when* version does not make sense as being a lover of fast food is a relatively permanent characteristic.

> You are a fast food lover.

**BE** in this sense is a stative verb.  It is one of such verbs "that describe states of being".  This characteristic applies not only when one is eating fast food.

From Thoughtco,

> ... a stative verb is a verb used primarily to describe a **state of being (I am**) or situation (I have). It's how something **is**, feels, or appears [emphasis added].

> The situations illustrated by "state" verbs are unchanging while they last and can continue for a long or indefinite time period.

Comment: Thanks for that. If I could have remembered "stative verb" I might have posted my comment as an answer. I knew there was a relevant term here - but I just couldn't call it to mind, so I settled for referring to "a relatively permanent characteristic".